# Pasar argumentos entre widgets flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo esta código que genera un listview.builder con los items extraídos de la base de datos. Ahora, necesito que cuando toque cada ítem se pase el id de ese ítem a la siguiente pantalla para trabajar con el y hacer otro procedimiento.

La función de pasar a la otra pagina funciona correctamente, pero al incluir el vehiculo.id dentro del procedimiento la función marca error. La base de datos es SQFlite.

La idea es pasar ese parametro a varias pantallas para generar calculos especificos con cada uno de los id por separado.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mipicoyplaca/modelos/vehiculo_model.dart';
import 'package:mipicoyplaca/paginas/mipicoyplaca.dart';
import 'package:mipicoyplaca/providers/db_provider.dart';

class VehiculosPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _VehiculosPageState createState() => _VehiculosPageState();
}

class _VehiculosPageState extends State<VehiculosPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0, horizontal: 10.0),
          child: _crearListaVehiculos()),
    );
  }

  Widget _crearListaVehiculos() {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: DBProvider.db.getTodosVehiculos(),
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<VehiculoModel>> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          final vehiculos = snapshot.data;
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: vehiculos.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, i) => _crearItem(context, vehiculos[i]),
          );
        } else {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _crearItem(BuildContext context, VehiculoModel vehiculo) {
    return Dismissible(
      key: UniqueKey(),
      onDismissed: (direccion) {
        DBProvider.db.deleteVehiculo(vehiculo.id);
      },
      child: Column(
        //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: <Widget>[
          RaisedButton(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
              elevation: 15.0,
              color: Colors.yellow,
              child: Text('${vehiculo.placa}',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 80.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MiPicoyPlaca(vehiculo.id)), //AQUÍ ESTA EL ERROR AL PASAR EL ARGUMENTO
                );
              }),
          Text('Desliza para eliminiar vehiculo',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20.0,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: que error tienes? y que contiene tu clase MiPicoyPlaca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me respondo a mi mismo, lo único que debes hacer es enviar un argumento con nombre a la siguiente pantalla. Y en esa pantalla capturarlo y trabajarlo.

Comment: Puedes dar un ejemplo? tu respuesta deja ambiguedades